# How to add a classpath in a workflow of Oozie on Cloudera

Tags: scala, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I have an application of scala, and packaged to jar, using maven

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <mainClass>mypackage.Check</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>mypackage.Check</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

As it showed, I've set the mainClass in pom.xml, in the local, I can run it correctly 
`java -jar normarevision-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /Users/Scala/normarevision/src/main/application.conf`

How to use it in Cloudera Oozie Workflow, 
[image]

I've tried `Check` o empty in `Mainclass` field, neither worked out.
Is there anything else needed to be configured?
[image]

Now I understand that it's the problem of classpath, it works find now with the fellowing commands:
`java –cp {SCALA_LIB}:myjar.jar mypackage.Check$delayedInit$body args`

`java –jar myjar.jar args`

`Java –cp {SCALA_LIB}:myjar.jar mypackage.Check args`
so the problem now turns to How to set the classpath in the workflow of Oozie in Cloudera.
Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Is this spark application or simple scala application ?

Comment: Oozie does not run a `java -jar` command-line; it requests YARN to start a JVM and run the Oozie "launcher" class, then that class runs your "main" class dynamically. In other words, can you run your stuff with `java -cp wtf-0.0.1.jar mypackage.Check wtf.conf`? If yes, then `mypackage.Check` is what Oozie expects as "main" class.

Comment: It'a a simply scala application, now I can run `java -cp scala-library-2.11.8.jar:wtf-0.0.1.jar mypackage.Check$delayedInit$body wtf.conf`,    but    `java -cp wtf-0.0.1.jar mypackage.Check wtf.conf` throw a error of  `Could not find or load main class ` also  `java -cp scala-library-2.11.8.jar:wtf-0.0.1.jar mypackage.Check wtf.conf`  doesn't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I found one way to solve it is change the configure of `job.property`file
`oozie.use.system.libpath=false` and copy all the library necessary to the `/lib` of the workspace directory. In my case, 
`/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-*****/lib`.